# Create a list from an existing list

Tags: python

I have a list `a = [1, 2, 3]` and I want to create an extension called `b = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I don't want to overwrite `a`, so I can not use *append*, *extend* or *insert*.
I wonder if there is a quick method for the job (faster than using a list of comprehension or *deep.copy*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, simple:

```
b = a + [4]
```